In munchkin, can a player re-negotiate helping after a curse is played?
Suppose a player is in combat, and another one agrees to help.
A different player plays a curse to make them lose the combat; can the helper leave combat? And the player change who is helping them (via bribe)?
Aside, can they now choose to flee instead of fighting it?

You always have to flee if you can't win the combat. Your helper can't decide to not help you once he has committed to help you. And your helper has to run away as well with all the mandatory dice roll on their own.

. . . or if somebody tries to help, and your fellow  party members
interfere so the two of you still cannot win . . . you must Run  Away.


If two players are cooperating and still can’t defeat the monster(s),
they must both Run Away. They roll separately for each monster, in whatever order they like. (If they can’t decide, roll the die; the high roller decides who  Runs Away first.) The monster(s) CAN catch them both.

